# What's the meaning of "The shock that followed this declaration found voice in a sustained 'Ah-h-h!'"

Tags: sentence-meaning, sentence-structure

The full sentence is:

> The shock that followed this declaration found voice in a sustained “Ah-h-h!" as the door of the coupe swung slowly open.

It's from Chapter 3 of «The Great Gatsby»

What does "The shock found voice in a sustained 'Ah-h-h'" mean?

Comment: Someone was shocked by something. That someone externalized his/her shock shouting "Ah-h-h!"

Comment: There is also a little wit or wordplay here. When we're shocked, we're often speechless, at a loss for words.  Here the shock **found voice**, that is "expressed itself".

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo I am not sure of the meaning of "found voice" here...

Comment: To **find voice** suggests that the voice was not immediately present.  It  had to be found. The phrase is a collocation, so that people don't think much  about it, but it means "to (eventually) express oneself".  The delay can be only momentary (as in your quotation) or it can be extended.  *The anger of the people in response to the government's actions, taken over a period of months, found voice in a violent protest in front of the White House.*  The anger ... found voice.

Answer (score 1):

Someone was shocked by a declaration (declaration = thing that someone said)

They expressed this shock by saying "Ah-h-h-h". Initially after the shock the person couldn't say anything, they were shocked to silence. They "found their voice" (became able to speak again) and what they said was "Ah-h-h-h"

To "find voice" means to express yourself after a period of silence.

A coupé is probably (given the age) a lightweight horse drawn carriage.

Answer (score 1):

> "The shock that followed this declaration found voice in a sustained “Ah-h-h!" as the door of the coupe swung slowly open".

The expression "find voice" (or "find a voice" really means to find *a way* to express yourself.

This expression doesn't necessary mean literally using one's voice. For example writers/authors speak of "finding a voice" which means discovering a way to express themselves in writing.

However, in this quotation I believe that there is also *[personification](https://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/Personification)* involved. The author is personifying the character's feeling of *shock*, and is implying that the *shock* "found voice", not any person.

This scene in *The Great Gatsby* is after the car crash, as a crowd gathers and watches as a man climbs out of the wreckage. I'm not 100% sure, but the "ah-h-h!" sound may actually be made by the car door slowly opening, in which case it isn't that any person or persons make this sound in shock, it just aptly illustrates the shock that was being felt. Alternatively it may be the collective sound made by the crowd as the door opened, in expectation of who may climb out and what state they may be in.